# codeigniter grabbing array from database

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and followed the guides but seem to be missing something. I have a simple database with customer records in it. My first goal in codeigniter is to simple list all my customers.

here is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');    //loads the HomeModel model
    $data = $this->HomeModel->function1();       //loads the function (function1) from the model

    $this->load->view('index', $data);    
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public function function1()
{
$query = $this->db->get('work_orders');
return $query->result();

}
```

here is my view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" id="invoice-details">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Work Order ID</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Description</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
     foreach ($data->result() as $row);?>
      <tr class="even gradeC">
      <td><a href="/WorkOrders/viewWo/<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>">
      <?php  echo $row['id']; ?></a></td>
      <td><?php  echo $row['status']; ?></td>
      <td><?php  echo Logic\System\Lib\Helper::trunc(htmlentities($row['description']), 8); ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: So what is the question? What are the results you're getting? How are they different from the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change on model :

```
public function function1()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('work_orders');
    //return $query->result();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Change on controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');    
    //$data = $this->HomeModel->function1(); 
    $data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->function1(); 
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

Change on view :

```
//foreach ($data->result() as $row);
    if(is_array($result)&&!empty($result))
        foreach ($result as $row);
```

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

[Views : Codeigniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

And Since you are using array on your view like `$row['id']`, you got to use result_array on model to return result set array:

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

[Generating Query Results : Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

You can use `$this->db->join();`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Produces:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs
JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Go through active record class guide .
[Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Thanks for the update. its starting to make sense. I tried your suggestions and I am getting:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in D:\Users\bnelson\Documents\My Web Sites\project1\application\views\index.php on line 57

Comment: May be your $result array is empty, check if the array is empty or not. Check updated answer.

Comment: nvm that worked, i had a typo on the index page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: there i think i marked it as answer correct. this is my 1st time using stackoverflow.

Comment: oh one more question if you dont mind. for joins, how do i do a join with array? i have this but its not right.


    public function companyList()
    {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('company');
    $this->db->join('contacts', 'contacts.id = company.primary_contact');
    return $query->result_array();

    }

Comment: just for the sake of completeness. `model-names` "MUST BE" first letter capital and the rest all lowercase, and the `model-file-name` MUST BE all lowercase. this may not cause any issues with a case-insensitive file system, but it will certainly be a pain when changing to a case sensitive file-system (if memory serves. your code will work on windows but not on linux).     

[http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html    under `Anatomy of a Model` second paragraph]

Answer (score 0):

In ur controller,u must pass the values as subarray of data array`$data['result']`.After which u can simply call it in view as `$result` .

Controller

```
$data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->function1();
```

And In view,

```
foreach ($result as $row){
 <?php  echo $row->id; ?>
..
}
```